# Warnings starting WildFly on Windows

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

When I run wildfly 8.2.0.Final on Windows 8.1 I get the following warnings in the log when starting the standalone-full profile:

```
WARN  [jacorb.codeset] (MSC service thread 1-8) Warning - unknown codeset (Cp1252) - defaulting to ISO-8859-1
WARN  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011600: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal
```

Everything seems to work fine, but I was wondering if someone can explain what these warnings are about and how to configure wildfly so these warnings are cleared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first warning you can take a look in this issue: [Windows: Unknown codeset (Cp1252), defaulting to ISO-8859-1](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1011849).

A possible work around is add to `JAVA_OPTS`

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
```

or

```
-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=ISO-8859-1
```

depending your file encoding.

For the second, you can add in the messaging subsystem `<journal-type>NIO</journal-type>`

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0">
    <hornetq-server>
        <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>
        <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>

        <!-- ... -->

    </hornetq-server>
</subsystem>
```

> **journal-type**
>
> Valid values are `NIO` or `ASYNCIO`.
>
> Choosing `NIO` chooses the Java `NIO` journal. Choosing `AIO` chooses the
>   Linux asynchronous IO journal. If you choose AIO but are not running
>   Linux or you do not have libaio installed then HornetQ will detect
>   this and automatically fall back to using `NIO`.

Ref: [Configuring the message journal](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/persistence.html#configuring.message.journal)

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore those warnings.

Regarding the first warning:

> [Cp1252] character encoding is a superset of ISO 8859-1, but differs
>   from the IANA's ISO-8859-1 by using displayable characters rather than
>   control characters in the 80 to 9F (hex) range [...]  It is known to Windows by the code page number 1252 (source:
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

Regarding the second warning:

> It's not possible to use the AIO journal under other operating systems
>   or earlier versions of the Linux kernel.
>   (source: http://hornetq.sourceforge.net/docs/hornetq-2.1.2.Final/user-manual/en/html/persistence.html#installing-aio)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I was hoping there was a way to supress the warnings instead of ignoring them.